# Java - unsynchronized getter

Tags: java, concurrency

I understand that getters should also be synchronized, but given below code

```
Object get() { return val; }

synchronized void set(Object val) { ... }
```

How can a compiler mess up a simple return statement, which is atomic (simple read from mem)? Is it related to per-processor cache?

Comment: What do you mean by _How can a compiler mess up a simple return statement_?

Comment: Why do you think getters should always be synchronized?

Comment: Read the last chapter of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html. The problem is precisely that a getter doesn't simply read from memory. It can read from a cache.

Comment: void get? What's that?

Comment: @alfa64 `Void` with a capital "V" is a valid class name. In fact, Java provides a `java.lang.Void`, though it can't be instantiated (references of type `Void` can only be `null`). You could create a `Void` of your own, though shadowing anything in `java.lang` is generally a bad idea.

Comment: I meant in the context of a getter, it was clearly a mistake.

Comment: Almost definitely, but less so than a capitalized `Synchronized` keyword. ;) I was just pointing out that you _could_ have a `com.mycompany.Void` and be returning it. But yes, I assume it was a mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and answers. And sorry for spelling issues, used my phone

Answer (score 5):

In this case, declaring the member variable `val` as `volatile` would suffice.

The problem is one of *visibility*. Without a memory barrier, there is no guarantee that changes written by one thread will become visible to another thread. Without a barrier, the JVM is allowed to make optimizations such as caching the values of member variables in a register, rather than writing changes to main memory where they are globally visible.

Answer (score 0):

Return statement might not even be atomic based on the return type. Basically if you return more than 4 bytes, then it's not atomic anymore. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756536/what-operations-in-java-are-considered-atomic)

Comment: In case of a reference it is always atomic.