# are all instructions in jvm atomic?

Tags: jvm

I remember I read the somewhere before,but I can't find the offical document now.

are all instructions in jvm all atomic?

like:

```
iinc
iload
aload
```

all atomic?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756536/what-operations-in-java-are-considered-atomic

Comment: I had read this question.He asks instructions in java.I means instructions in JVM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bytecode instructions you mentioned (`iinc`, `iload`, `aload` etc.) operate on the values from the *operand stack* and on the *local variables*. These areas are thread-local (see JVMS [2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5), [2.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6)), that is, speaking about atomicity here is meaningless. I.e. they are NOT implemented using atomic CPU instructions like `lock xadd`, but nobody should care.

The bytecode instructions that read or write fields and array elements (`getfield`, `putfiled`, `iastore` etc.) are atomic except for `long` and `double` types (see JLS [17.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7)). 32-bit JVM may implement (actually, HotSpot JVM *does* implement) reading and writing of 64-bit fields with two 32-bit loads or stores, unless the field is declared `volatile`.