# Why is reference assignment atomic in Java?

Tags: java, scala, concurrency, jvm, atomic

As far as I know reference assignment is atomic in a 64 bit JVM.
Now, I assume the jvm doesn't use atomic pointers internally to model this, since otherwise there would be no need for Atomic References. So my questions are:

Is atomic reference assignment in the "specs" of java/Scala and guaranteed to happen or is it just a happy coincidence that it is that way most times ?

Is atomic reference assignment implied for any language that compiles to the JVM's bytecode (e.g. clojure, Groovy, JRuby, JPython...etc) ?

How can reference assignment be atomic without using an atomic pointer internally ?

Comment: @JornVernee I meant assignment not swapping, thanks for the correction

Comment: This might give a first clue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23232242/are-all-instructions-in-jvm-atomic

Comment: I did... however I've been searching all over the internet for how getfield, putfiled and iastore are implemented and I haven't found an explaination that doesn't involve digging through the openjvm code, which I'm not proficient enough to do :(

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First of all, reference assignment is atomic because the [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) says so. Besides that, there is no obstacle for [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) implementors to fulfill this constraint, as 64 Bit references are usually only used on [64 Bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing) architectures, where atomic 64 Bit assignment comes for free.

Your main confusion stems from the assumption that the additional “Atomic References” feature means exactly that, due to its name. But the [`AtomicReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) class offers far more, as it encapsulates a `volatile` reference, which has stronger memory visibility guarantees in a multi-threaded execution.

Having an atomic reference update does not necessarily imply that a thread reading the reference will also see consistent values regarding the *fields* of the object reachable through that reference. All it guarantees is that you will read either the `null` reference or a valid reference to an existing object that actually was stored by some thread. If you want more guarantees, you need constructs like synchronization, `volatile` references, or an `AtomicReference`.

`AtomicReference` also offers *atomic update* operations like `compareAndSet` or `getAndSet`. These are not possible with ordinary reference variables using built-in language constructs (but only with special classes like `AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater` or `VarHandle`).

Comment: "Having an atomic reference update does not necessarily imply that a thread reading the reference will also see consistent values regarding the fields of the object reachable through that reference."  Are you implying that AtomicReference make an object safe to mutate in a multi-threaded enviornment ? Because I can hardly believe this to be true.  As far as I know with or without an AtomicReference you CAN'T modify an object thread safely without mutexes or synchronized

Comment: My question was as to the nature of the 64/32 bits value that is the reference itself no the object stored by the reference.

Comment: @George: setting an `AtomicReference` guarantees the visibility of all updates made to that object *before* publishing it through that `AtomicReference`, not that you are allowed to make updates *after* that. Publishing an object through an ordinary reference variable does not make any guaranty regarding updates, regardless of whether you make them before or after that. It doesn’t even guaranty that other threads will ever see the new reference.

Comment: You clearly said “*otherwise there would be no need for Atomic References*”, hence, it was required to explain why we still need Atomic References, even if reads and writes to references are atomic per se.

Comment: What I said is "I assume the jvm doesn't use atomic pointers internally to model this, since otherwise there would be no need for Atomic References"... it was a figure of speech for saying "Whilst I don't know the java specifications I'm quite sure references aren't modeled internally as an atomic pointer since they do not have all the atomic pointer opeartion hence the need for the AtomicReference"

Comment: "AtomicReference guarantees the visibility of all updates made to that object before publishing it through that AtomicReference" Care to elaborate on this ? "Publishing" is not an action in Java. If by publishing your mean assigning then that is already the case with normal references, is it not ?

Comment: @George: Let's assume you have 2 threads. In one a normal reference is assigned (`ref = object;`), and in the other one it is directly read afterwards (`Object localObject = ref;`). With normal references you have the guarantee that 1. The assignment is at some point of time visible to other threads and 2. `localObject` gets a valid value - which might not necessarily be the latest one which has been written. If you use AtomicReferences instead you would also have the guarantee that the write will be immediately visible to the other thread and that the read from that thread will pick it up.

Comment: An “atomic pointer” isn’t necessarily an “atomic reference”, in the sense of `AtomicReference`. Hence, it was necessary to point out that references (i.e. the underlying pointers) *are* atomic, still don’t match the functionality of an `AtomicReference`.

Comment: “Publishing” means assigning to a variable that is visible to other threads. And no, there are no guaranties regarding visibility of previous updates when publishing though normal references. If you write `point=new Point(42,100)` and `point` is neither `final` nor `volatile`, other threads *may* see the new reference, while still seeing the default value (`0`) for either, `x` or `y `, or both (in the absence of other synchronization).

Comment: Do you have any code snipets to back this up ? I though the whole idea behind Java references was that this kind of torn read was not possible. So if you had a point = new Point(0,0) and then you assigned to it: pointer = new Point(42,100)  threads reading at the same time might read either Point(0,0) or Pointer(42,100) but never a value in between as you mention.

Comment: This is not about an older instance; the reference might have been `null` before the assignment, that doesn’t matter. The issue is, `new Point(42,100)` is not an atomic operation. It creates a new `Point` instance, all fields being at their default value (`0` for `int`), then, the constructor will be executed, which will assign the values `42` to `x` and `100` to `y`, then the reference is assigned to `point`, *from a single thread’s point of view*. A different thread may see these actions out of order, see the reference to the new `Point` instance without seeing the effect of the assignments.

Comment: This doesn’t apply to immutable objects. If you declare `x` and `y` as `final`, they’re immune to such data races. Alternatively, you may declare `point` as `final`, but this implies that the whole action is part of a constructor or initializer. Or, well, declaring `point` as `volatile` ensures that other threads see all previous updates (`x=42; y=100;`) when seeing the new `Point` instance through the `point` reference.

Comment: Wait ? Isn't construction guaranteed to be done before the object is assigned ? As in isn't var a = new X() executed as: X() -> memory address assigned to a ?

Comment: I can’t say anything about Scala, but for Java, when using multi-threading without proper thread safe constructs, it is not guaranteed. You may read [JLS §17.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4), if you are interested.

Comment: However the question I didn't ask is related to: ', where atomic 64 Bit assignment comes for free' .... is this true ? I couldn't find any reference to this being the case in a multi-cpu environment. I actually don't know assembler so the only way I could "test" it is to see if gcc optimizez away atomic<T *> to T * with march=native and ofast and it doesn't, there are extra instructions generated for the atomic version. But then again its very stupid and uncertain to assume gcc will produce optimal code and, as I said before, I don't know shit about x64 (or any) assembler

Comment: @Holger nitpick: `If you declare x and y as final` it is `OR` not `AND`. It is enough for a single field to be final so that a `StoreStore|LoadStore` barrier to be inserted at the end of the constructor.

Comment: @Eugene: there are no such barriers in the specification. You are drawing wrong conclusions from implementation details. The specification clearly says that this is *not guaranteed*, [even by example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#d5e34106).

Comment: @George: mind the word “usually” in that sentence. You don’t have to care about these details, as that’s up to the JVM developers. It is, by the way, entirely irrelevant what gcc does, as HotSpot’s JIT compiler generates code directly for the target platform, gcc is not involved. I don’t know what C++’ `atomic<T *>` implies, perhaps, it’s like Java’s `AtomicReference`, which, as already explained, does a lot more than just atomic assignment. Of course, the JVM/JIT developers have to know what is needed to get the atomic reference behavior, e.g. usually the correct alignment is required, etc.

Comment: @Holger yes. I should have said *under the current implementation, DONT Do IT, Listen to the JLS*, thank you. http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/4d9931ebf861/src/share/vm/opto/parse1.cpp#l955

Answer (score 10):

Atomic reference assignment is in the specs.

> Writes to and reads of references are always atomic, regardless of
>   whether they are implemented as 32 or 64 bit values.

Quoted from *JSR-133: Java(TM) Memory Model and Thread Specification*, section 12 *Non-atomic Treatment of `double` and `long`*, http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr133.pdf.

Comment: Ok, that answers the first part but not the other 2. To be honest the thing that I'm most curios about here is how this behavior happens if references are not atomic pointers and that's related to how one would implement a JVM rather than the specifications for java and/or the jvm.

Comment: True. I on purpose did not pretend to be a wiseguy on matters where I’m not sure. The way I understand it, though, this is a spec of the JVM, so I would expect it to cover all languages running on the JVM. And the way I read it, in requires internal pointer operations to happen atomically (at least as seen from outside the JVM).

Comment: Well yes, but I doubt those are actual atomic pointer operations since otherwise things like compare and swap would also be atomic using standard references.

Comment: Nice answer - good find; my vote for that. And thanks for leaving out that small part that left room for my answer ;-)

Comment: The linked PDF describes the memory model for Java 5 proposed by JSR133. To prove that it indeed made it into the Java 5 JLS and is still there today, it’s better to link to [JLS §17.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @Holger, I agree completely. The quote there is exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

As the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44284401/642706) outlines, the Java Memory Model states that references read/writes are atomic.

But of course, that is the Java *language* memory model. On the other hand: no matter if we talk Java or Scala or Kotlin or ... in the end everything gets compiled into **bytecode**.

There are no special bytecode instructions for Java. Scala in the end uses the very same instructions.

Leading to: the properties of that memory model must be implemented **inside** the VM platform. Thus they *must* apply to other languages running on the platform as well.

Comment: Since the name was ' JavaTM Memory Model' I was unsure if it referred to the JVM as a whole and as such I assumed there might be instructions to non atomically asign available to other JVM languages

Comment: Back then when that memory model was written, there was only the Java language on the Java VM platform. Methinks.

Comment: Even now, I don't think there are JVM instructions that aren't used by Java itself.

Comment: "But of course, that is the Java language memory model." Not really. It describes behavior of both Java language and Java virtual machines, and generally makes it clear which is which. Mostly it talks about VMs, and this section in particular does too: "Java virtual machines are free to perform writes to long and double values atomically or in two parts".

Comment: @Jasper-M: there are. E.g., `swap` is never used by `javac` generated code. In Java 7, the `invokedynamic` instruction was not used by Java itself, which is quite a big feature of that JVM version…

Comment: @Holger In my defense, *now* `invokedynamic` is used by java itself. :-p Didn't know about `swap` though. Thanks!

Comment: One thing to keep in mind when drawing this conclusion, is, that this only applies if the concepts of that other language (i.e. references) are compiled 1:1 to the equivalent byte code artifacts. E.g. a reference of a particular language might be so far away from what Java’s object references do, that it doesn’t match a sole byte code reference variable, but, e.g. a compound data structure. For Java, it is impossible to encounter an object reference having a not-yet-initialized vtable, but that doesn’t have to apply to another language, having an entirely different method dispatch algorithm.