# Java garbage collection in multithreaded application for local variable

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection, java.util.concurrent

I have following use-case:

- Need a single background thread which maintains a set of accountIDs in memory and it fetches the latest accountIds every 1 second
- Other multiple parallel running process will search if particular accountID is present in above Set or not

To achieve above use-case, I have following code. `runTask()` is a method which is responsible for fetching new Set every 1 second. `doesAccountExist` method is called by other parallel threads to check if accountId exists in the Set or not.

```
class AccountIDFetcher {
 private Set<String> accountIds;
 private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;

 public AccountIDFetcher() {
   this.accountIds = new HashSet<String>();
   scheduledThreadPoolExecutor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
   scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(this::runTask, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 }

// Following method runs every 1 second
 private void runTask() {
   accountIds = getAccountIds()
 }

 // other parallel thread calls below method
 public boolean doesAccountExist(String accountId) {
   return accountIds.contains(instanceId);
 }

 private Set<String> getAccountIds() {
   Set<String> accounts = new HashSet<String>();
   // calls Database and put list of accountIds into above set
   return accounts;
 }

}
```

**I have following question**

1. In runTask method, I just change the reference of accountIds variable to a new object. So if, Thread-2 is in the middle of searching accountId in doesAccountExist() method and at the same time if Thread-1 executes runTask() & changes the reference of accountIds variable to a new object then old object gets orphaned. is it possible that old object can be garbage collected before Thread-2 finish searching in it?

Comment: Oops, typo in your code. `instanceId` in `doesAccountExist` should be `accountId`, am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

You asked:

> is it possible that old object can be garbage collected before Thread-2 finish searching in it?

No, the old `Set` object does *not* become garbage while some thread is still using it.

An object only becomes a candidate for [garbage-collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) after *each and every* reference to said object (a) goes out of scope, (b) is set to null, or (c) is a [weak reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference).

## No, an object in use within a method will not be garbage-collected

In Java, an object reference assignment is atomic, as discussed in [another Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44283378/642706). When `this.accountIds` is directed to point to a new `Set` object, that happens in one logical operation. That means that any other code in any other thread accessing the `accountIds` member field will always successfully access either the old `Set` object or the new `Set` object, always one or the other.

If during that re-assignment another thread accessed the old `Set` object, that other thread's code is working with a copy of the object reference. You can think of your `doesAccountExist` method:

```java
 public boolean doesAccountExist(String accountId) {
   return accountIds.contains(accountId);
 }
```

…as having a local variable with a copy of the object reference, as if written like this:

```java
 public boolean doesAccountExist(String accountId) {
   Set<String> set = this.accountIds ;
   return set.contains(accountId);
 }
```

While one thread is replacing the reference to a new `Set` on the member field `accountIds`, the `doesAccountExist` method already has a copy of the reference to the old `Set`. At that moment, while one thread is changing the member field reference, and another thread has a local reference, the garbage collector sees both the new and old `Set` objects as having (at least) one reference each. So neither is a candidate for being garbage-collected.

Actually, more technically correct would be explaining that at the point in your line `return accountIds.contains(accountId);` where execution reaches the `accountIds` portion, the current (old) `Set` will be accessed. A moment later the `contains` method begins its work, during which re-assigning a new `Set` to that member field has no effect on this method's work-in-progress already using the old `Set`.

This means that even after the new `Set` has been assigned in one thread, the other thread may still be continuing its work of searching the old `Set`. This may or may not be a problem depending on the business context of your app. But your Question did not address this stale-data transactional aspect.

So regarding your question:

> is it possible that old object can be garbage collected before Thread-2 finish searching in it?

No, the old `Set` object does *not* become garbage while some thread is still using it.

## Other issues

Your code does have other issues.

### Visibility

You declared your member field as `private Set<String> accountIds;`. If you access that member field across threads on a host machine with multiple cores, then you have a visibility problem. The caches on each core may not be refreshed immediately when you assign a different object to that member field. As currently written, it is entirely possible that one thread accessing `this.accountIds` will gain access to the old `Set` object even after that variable was assigned the new `Set` object.

If you do not already know about the issues I mention, study up on concurrency. There is more involved than I can cover here. Learn about the [Java Memory Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model). And I *strongly* recommend reading and re-reading the classic book, [*Java Concurrency in Practice*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/127932.Java_Concurrency_in_Practice) by Brian Goetz, et al.

#### `volatile`

One solution is to mark the member field as `volatile`. So, this:

```
private Set<String> accountIds;
```

…becomes this:

```
volatile private Set<String> accountIds;
```

Marking as `volatile` avoids a stale cache on a CPU core pointing to the old object reference rather than the new object reference.

#### `AtomicReference`

Another solution is using an object of `AtomicReference` class as the member field. I would mark it `final` so that one and only one such object is ever assigned to that member field, so the field is a constant rather than a variable. Then assign each new `Set` object as the payload contained within that `AtomicReference` object. Code wanting the current `Set` object calls a getter method on that `AtomicReference` object. This call is guaranteed to be thread-safe, eliminating the need for `volatile`.

### Concurrent access to existing `Set`

Another possible problem with your code might be concurrent access to an existing `Set`. If you have more than one thread accessing the existing `Set`, then you must protect that resource.

One way to protect access to that `Set` is to use a thread-safe implementation of `Set` such as [`ConcurrentSkipListSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html).

From what you have showed in the Question, the only access to the existing `Set` that I noticed is calling [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#contains(java.lang.Object)). If you are never modifying the existing `Set`, then merely calling contains across multiple threads *may* be safe — I just don't know, you'd have to research it.

If you intend to never modify an existing `Set`, then you can enforce that by using an [unmodifiable set](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#unmodifiable). One way to produce an unmodifiable set is to construct and populate a regular set. Then feed that regular set to the method [`Set.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection)). So your `getAccountIds` method would look like this:

```java
 private Set<String> getAccountIds() {
   Set<String> accounts = new HashSet<String>();
   // calls Database and put list of accountIds into above set
   return Set.copyOf( accounts );
 }
```

### Return a copy rather a reference

There are two easy ways to avoid dealing with concurrency:

- Make the object [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)
- Provide a copy of the object

As for the first way, immutability, the [Java Collections Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework) is generally very good but unfortunately lacks explicit mutability & immutability in its type system. The `Set.of` methods and [`Collections.unmodifiableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSet(java.util.Set)) both provide a `Set` that cannot be modified. But the type itself does not proclaim that fact. So we cannot ask the compiler to enforce a rule such as our `AtomicReference` only storing an immutable set. As an alternative, consider using a third-party collections with immutability as part of its type. Perhaps [*Eclipse Collections*](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/) or [*Google Guava*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava).

As for the second way, we can make a copy of our `Set` of account IDs whenever needing access. So we need a `getCurrentAccountIds` method that goes into the `AtomicReference`, retrieves the `Set` stored there, and called `Set.copyOf` to produce a new set of the same contained objects. This copy operation is not documented as being thread-safe. So we should mark the method `synchronized` to allow only one copy operation at a time. Bonus: We can mark this method `public` to give any calling programmer access to the `Set` of account IDs for their own perusal.

```java
    synchronized public Set < UUID > getCurrentAccountIds ( )
    {
        return Set.copyOf( this.accountIdsRef.get() ); // Safest approach is to return a copy rather than original set.
    }
```

Our convenience method `doesAccountExist` should call that same `getCurrentAccountIds` to obtain a copy of the set before doing its "contains" logic. This way we do not care whether or not the "contains" work is thread-safe.

Caveat: I am not satisfied with using `Set.copyOf` to as means to avoid any possible thread-safety issues. That method notes that if the passed collection being copied is already an unmodifiable set, then a copy may not be made. In real work I would use a `Set` implementation that guarantees thread-safety whether found bundled with Java or by adding a third-party library.

### Do not use object within constructor

I do not like seeing the scheduled executor service appearing within your constructor. I see two issues there: (a) app lifecycle and (b) using an object within a constructor.

Creating the executor service, scheduling tasks on that service, and shutting down that service are all related to the lifecycle of the app. An object generally should not be aware of its lifecycle within the greater app. This account IDs provider object should know only how to do its job (provide IDs) but should not be responsible for putting itself to work. So your code is [mixing responsibilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle), which is generally a poor practice.

Another problem is that the executor service is being scheduled to immediately start using the very object that we are still constructing. Generally, the best practice is to *not* use an object while still under construction. You may get away with such use, but doing so is risky and is prone to leading to bugs. A constructor should be short and sweet, used just to validate inputs, establish required resources, and ensure the integrity of the object being birthed.

I did not pull the service out of your constructor only because I did not want to this Answer to go too far out into the weeds. However, I did make two adjustments. (a) I changed the initial delay on the `scheduleWithFixedDelay` call from zero to one second. This is a hack to give the constructor time to finish birthing the object before its first use. (b) I added the `tearDown` method to properly shutdown the executor service so its backing thread-pool does not continue running indefinitely in zombie fashion.

## Tips

I suggest renaming your `getAccountIds()` method. The `get` wording in Java is usually associated with the JavaBeans convention of accessing an existing property. In your case you are generating an entirely new replacement set of values. So I would change that name to something like `fetchFreshAccountIds`.

Consider wrapping your scheduled task with a try-catch. Any `Exception` or `Error` bubbling up to reach the `ScheduledExecutorService` brings a silent halt to any further scheduling. See [*ScheduledExecutorService Exception handling*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6894595/642706).

## Example code.

Here is a complete example of my take on your code.

Caveat: Use at your own risk. I am *not* a concurrency expert. This is meant as food-for-thought, not production use.

I used [`UUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/UUID.html) as the data type of the account IDs to be more realistic and clear.

I changed some of your class & method names for clarity.

Notice which methods are private and which are public.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class AccountIdsProvider
{
    // Member fields
    private AtomicReference < Set < UUID > > accountIdsRef;
    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;

    // Constructor
    public AccountIdsProvider ( )
    {
        this.accountIdsRef = new AtomicReference <>();
        this.accountIdsRef.set( Set.of() ); // Initialize to empty set.
        this.scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay( this :: replaceAccountIds , 1 , 1 , TimeUnit.SECONDS );  // I strongly suggest you move the executor service and the scheduling work to be outside this class, to be a different class’ responsibility.
    }

    // Performs database query to find currently relevant account IDs.
    private void replaceAccountIds ( )
    {
        // Beware: Any uncaught Exception or Error bubbling up to the scheduled executor services halts the scheduler immediately and silently.
        try
        {
            System.out.println( "Running replaceAccountIds. " + Instant.now() );
            Set < UUID > freshAccountIds = this.fetchFreshAccountIds();
            this.accountIdsRef.set( freshAccountIds );
            System.out.println( "freshAccountIds = " + freshAccountIds + " at " + Instant.now() );
        }
        catch ( Throwable t )
        {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Task to be run by scheduled executor service.
    private Set < UUID > fetchFreshAccountIds ( )
    {
        int limit = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 0 , 4 );
        HashSet < UUID > uuids = new HashSet <>();
        for ( int i = 1 ; i <= limit ; i++ )
        {
            uuids.add( UUID.randomUUID() );
        }
        return Set.copyOf( uuids ); // Return unmodifiable set.
    }

    // Calling programmers can get a copy of the set of account IDs for their own perusal.
    // Pass a copy rather than a reference for thread-safety.
    // Synchronized in case copying the set is not thread-safe.
    synchronized public Set < UUID > getCurrentAccountIds ( )
    {
        return Set.copyOf( this.accountIdsRef.get() ); // Safest approach is to return a copy rather than original set.
    }

    // Convenience method for calling programmers.
    public boolean doesAccountExist ( UUID accountId )
    {
        return this.getCurrentAccountIds().contains( accountId );
    }

    // Destructor
    public void tearDown ( )
    {
        // IMPORTANT: Always shut down your executor service. Otherwise the backing pool of threads may run indefinitely, like a zombie ‍.
        if ( Objects.nonNull( this.scheduledExecutorService ) )
        {
            System.out.println( "INFO - Shutting down the scheduled executor service. " + Instant.now() );
            this.scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();  // I strongly suggest you move the executor service and the scheduling work to be outside this class, to be a different class’ responsibility.
        }
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "INFO - Starting app. " + Instant.now() );
        AccountIdsProvider app = new AccountIdsProvider();
        try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 10 ).toMillis() ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        app.tearDown();
        System.out.println( "INFO - Ending app. " + Instant.now() );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot @basil-bourque. The other thread which still may be searching in old Set is not a problem. In my app, it's fine to return stale data to that thread. But it was not fine for that thread to throw unnecessary exception if in the middle of search operation the Old Set was garbage collected. That's what i wanted to confirm

Comment: it's either really late for me or this is not entirely correct. GC wise, sure, a strongly referenced instance is not going to be collected, agreed. But you can think that method can be re-written like this: `public boolean doesAccountExist(String accountId) { int size = accountIds.size(); for(int i=0;i<size;++i){ if(accountIds.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(accountId)){ return true;}} return false;}` and this, to me, can trivially throw an Exception when two threads update `accountIds` to be of different sizes. Even using `contains`, like the OP does, could result in such scenarios. I _think_.

Comment: @Eugene Yes, looping on a `Set` being modified by another thread is problematic. But that is not the problem asked in the Question. The Question was specifically about an object being garbage-collected when in use in one thread while being replaced as the target of an object reference in a member field. I do not even see any code in the Question related to modifying the `Set` after instantiation. The code seen in the Question swaps out one `Set` object for another, and accesses the member field only a single time when calling `contains`. So what part of the Answer is "not entirely correct"?

Comment: your answer suggests that "this is fine" to replace the `Set` reference like this. You imply that the other threads will just iterate their own copy, without any interference with the already changed copy. I have shown a very simple example (that you seem to agree with), where this will break. The example was supposed to prove that you have no idea what `contains` _might_ do internally and how it might iterate the `Set`. Adding visibility constraints and even copying is of no help - you are still updating a _shared_ instance.

Comment: even your bold statement: "No, an object in use within a method will not be garbage-collected" is not correct, see this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58714980/rejectedexecutionexception-inside-single-executor-service). you seem to confuse reachability and scope.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection is not the main issue with this code. The lack of any synchronization is the main issue.

If thread-2 is "searching" in something, it necessarily has a reference to that thing, so it's not going to get GC'd.

Why not use 'synchronized' so you can be sure of what will happen?

Comment: In my app, it's fine for Thread-2 to return the stale data. we don't want to take a performance hit and use something like ConcurrentHashSet

Comment: A "performance hit" for a once-a-second operation?

Answer (score 0):

garbage collection wise, you will not get into any surprise, but not because the accepted answer implies. It is somehow more tricky.

May be visualizing this will help.

```
  accountIds ----> some_instance_1
```

Suppose `ThreadA` is now working with `some_instance_1`. It started to search for `accountId` in it. While that operation is going, `ThreadB` changes what that reference is pointing to. So it becomes:

```
                   some_instance_1
  accountIds ----> some_instance_2
```

Because reference assign is atomic, this is what `ThreadA` will see also, if it reads that reference again. At this point in time, `some_instance_1` is eligible for garbage collection, since no one refers to it. Just take note, that this will only happen if `ThreadA` *sees* this write that `ThreadB` did. Either way : you are safe (`gc` wise only), because `ThreadA` either works with a stale copy (which you said it's OK) or the most recent one.

This does not mean that everything is fine with your code.

---

What that answer gets right indeed is that reference assigning is `atomic`, so once a thread writes to a reference (`accountIds = getAccountIds()`), a *reading* thread (`accountIds.contains(instanceId);`) that will indeed perform the read will see the write. I say "indeed" because an optimizer might not even issue such a read, to begin with. In very simple (and somehow wrong) words, each thread might get its own copy of `accountIds` and because that is a "plain" read without any special semantics (like `volatile`, `release/acquire`, `synchronization`, etc), reading threads have no obligation to see the writing thread action.

So, even if someone actually did `accountIds = getAccountIds()`, it does not mean that reading threads will see this. And it gets worse. This write might not *ever* be seen. You need to introduce special semantics if you want guarantees (and you absolutely do).

For that you need to make your `Set` `volatile`:

```
private volatile Set<String> accountIds = ...
```

so that when multi threads are involved, you would get the needed visibility guarantees.

Then not to interfere with any in-flight updates of `accountIds`, you can simply work on a local copy of it:

```
 public boolean doesAccountExist(String accountId) {
      Set<String> local = accountIds;
      return local.contains(accountId);
 }
```

Even if `accountIds` change while you are in this method, you do not care about that change, since you are searching against `local`, which is unaware of the change.