# JVM instruction vs assembly instruction: which is atomic?

Tags: java, atomic

Single JVM instruction is not atomic but single assemble instruction is atomic.
Is this correct?

Demo

```
public class DemoInstruction {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=0;
        i++;
    }
}
```

`i++` translate into JVM instruction:

```
    IINC 1 1
```

`i++` translates into local assembly instructions consisting of three assembly instructions.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/23232242 but I'm not sure, as I'm having difficulty understanding your English.

Comment: *but single assembly instruction is atomic* - no, not true.  Even CISC machines like x86 that can run a memory-destination add or increment as a single instruction like `inc dword ptr [rdi]` don't do it atomically unless you use a special prefix in the machine code to make that happen.  [Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39396999).  `lock inc dword ptr [rdi]` is atomic, and what C++ compilers use for `std::atomic<int>`.  Or what JVMs use for AtomicInteger.

Comment: @Sweeper: you might want to add [Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39396999) to the duplicate list; it's a canonical Q&A about atomicity in assembly, including the fact that a single asm instruction is only atomic on a single-core machine.  I can't add it myself since unfortunately I'm only about half way to an [atomic] tag badge, and this isn't tagged [assembly] despite the question being about that.