# Is the given code thread safe?

Tags: scala

```
@volatile var aVector = Vector(1, 2, 3)
```

thread one

```
aVector +:= getAnInt()
```

thread two

```
aVector match {
  case head +: tail =>
    doSomethingWith(head)
    aVector = tail
  case _ =>
}
```

JVM version: HotSpot 1.8

Scala version: 2.10.5

Answer (score 8):

Short answer: NO.

`+:=` is *not* an atomic operation, as well as deconstruction `+:` and assignment.

So you can have two scenarios when everything is going wrong:

1. First thread reads the Vector, appends an element, (at this moment second thread reads the Vector, removes the element and reassigns the Vector `var`), first thread reassigns the `var` with appended Vector.

In this scenario first element of the Vector (that was appended by first thread) will be processed twice.

2. Second thread reads the Vector and processes first element (first thread kicks in, reads vector, appends element), second thread reassigns Vector `var` with the value without first element.

In this case element that was appended by first thread will be lost.

There are several possible ways how to make this code thread safe:

1. You can use java's concurrent queue (probably the best and easiest approach)
2. If you want to go scala-way, you should consider using actors as producer-consumer
3. You can design your own synchronization solution

### Upd

Some clarifications about `@volatile` and operations on immutable collections.
Scala annotation `@volatile` is basically java's volatile keyword. In this case it makes assignments of `var aVector` atomic and immediately visible in other threads, but it doesn't make sequence of (read - update - assign operations) atomic or synchronized.

This scala code:

```
@volatile var aVector = Vector(1, 2, 3)
aVector +:= 1
```

Compiles to this java:

```
public final class _$$anon$1 {
  private volatile Vector<Object> aVector = package$.MODULE$.Vector().apply(Predef$.MODULE$.wrapIntArray(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }));

  private Vector<Object> aVector() {
    return (Vector<Object>)this.aVector;
  }

  private void aVector_$eq(final Vector<Object> x$1) {
    this.aVector = x$1;
  }

  {
    this.aVector_$eq(this.aVector().$plus$colon(BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger(1), Vector$.MODULE$.canBuildFrom()));
  }
}
```

As you can see, Vector gets read, updated and assigned back via non-atomic sequence of function calls. Second thread can update it in-between.

Comment: I marked aVector as @volatile,and I suppose`aVector +:= getAnInt()
`will be compile to something like `aVector.synchronized {
  aVector +:= getAnInt()
}`.If not,did @volatile make any change in this case?

Comment: @Renkai `@volatile` compiles to `volatile` in java. See update of my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Code below shows it is not thread safe in action,but I'm still confusing about the volatile annotation.

```
object TryThreadSafe {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    @volatile var aVector = Vector(1, 2, 3)
    val thread = new Thread(new Runnable {
      override def run(): Unit = {
        aVector :+= getAnInt()
      }
    })
    thread.start()
    while (aVector.nonEmpty) {
      aVector match {
        case head +: tail =>
          doSomethingWith(head)
          aVector = tail
        case _ =>
      }
    }
    thread.join()
    while (aVector.nonEmpty) {
      aVector match {
        case head +: tail =>
          doSomethingWith(head)
          aVector = tail
        case _ =>
      }
    }
    //print 1 2 3 1 2 3 4
  }

  def getAnInt() = {
    Thread.sleep(10000)
    4
  }

  def doSomethingWith(head: Int) = {
    println(head)
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is confusing? Are you aware how [volatile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) works in Java?

Comment: @Aivean Yes,and it seems volatile doesn't make any difference because assignment is atomic by default http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756536/what-operations-in-java-are-considered-atomic

Comment: well, you can say that non-volatile reference assignment is atomic, but it is not guaranteed to be immediately reflected in other threads. From your link: ` atomicity does not imply visibility. So while another thread is guaranteed not to see a partially written int, it may never see the new value.`