# Java: How to atomically replace all values in a Map?

Tags: java, multithreading, dictionary, concurrency

I have a stateful bean in an multi-threaded enviroment, which keeps its state in a map. Now I need a way to replace all values of that map in one atomic action.

```
public final class StatefulBean {

    private final Map<String, String> state = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();

    public StatefulBean() {
        //Initial state
        this.state.put("a", "a1");
        this.state.put("b", "b1");
        this.state.put("c", "c1");
    }

    public void updateState() {
        //Fake computation of new state
        final Map<String, String> newState = new HashMap<>();
        newState.put("b", "b1");
        newState.put("c", "c2");
        newState.put("d", "d1");

        atomicallyUpdateState(newState);
        /*Expected result
         *  a: removed
         *  b: unchanged
         *  C: replaced
         *  d: added*/
    }

    private void atomicallyUpdateState(final Map<String, String> newState) {
        //???
    }
}
```

At the moment I use `ConcurrentSkipListMap` as implementation of a `ConcurrentMap`, but that isn't a requirement.

The only way I see to solve this problem is to make the global `state` `volatile` and completely replace the map or use a `AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater`.
Is there a better way?

My updates are quite frequent, once or twice a second, but chance only very few values. Also the whole map will only ever contain fewer than 20 values.

Comment: Might it be easier to build a new map with the updated values and then swap it in atomically? Depends on whether your client code retains references to the map or the bean, I guess?

Comment: Do you need `updateState` to be atomic?

Comment: @schaffe no, only the `atomicallyUpdateState` to be atomic

Comment: What race condition do you think to avoid by swapping atomically?

Comment: @brabster Only the bean will be referenced, the map itself will be totally private
It feels kind of wrong to build and swap the whole map to only update a few values. But maybe my feeling is wrong and replacing is the best way.

Comment: @bowmore  I try to avoid an inconsistent state: `this.state = new HashMap(newState);` I fear that between creating and assigning the new state the thread gets interupted and a different thread replaces some values, which than will be reverted when the first thread continues

Comment: Currently this.state is final, you cannot reassign it. It's also not clear if the entirety of the map is exposed (is there a getter or so that returns the Map?). So I'm still not clear about what problem you try to avoid. Somehow you imply that the different entries have a semantic relationship that matters to clients of the class, which?

Comment: @Jan then you need a way to lock access to the map for the time of update. Locking is a simplest approach, but it is also possible to apply 
versioning and CAS here.

Comment: @Jan replacing the value (i.e. the whole map) would seem to be the simplest solution and unless there's any significant performance concerns (although using locking is likely to perform worse and less predictably unless the map is huge) I'd try that before anything requiring more advanced knowledge. It's how a functional programmer would do it. - added as an answer.

Comment: @bowmore The map itself will be hidden from its clients, values will be only accessed via "value getter" `public String getValue(String key) {...}`
While there are lot of updates to the map, singular values might only be updated after minutes or even hours.
The values will be used for further computations and decisions in my programm: If an allready updated value is replaced through an older version because of a racecondition, that would leave my programm in an incorrect state for quite some time
I can change the `StatefullBean` and make the map non-`final`.

Comment: I assume that a client calling `getValue()` with two different keys in succession is supposed to get values of the same state? However if you internally change the state (atomic or otherwise) you cannot guarantee that. You can't, because the (atomic) state change can happen between the two `getValue()` calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approach with CAS and [`AtomicReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) would be to copy map content on each bulk update.

```
AtomicReference<Map<String, String>> workingMapRef = new AtomicReference<>(new HashMap<>());
```

This map can be concurrent, but for "bulk updates" it is read-only. Then in `updateState` looping `doUpdateState()` until you get true and that means that your values has been updated.

```
void updateState() {
    while (!doUpdateState());
}

boolean doUpdateState() {
    Map<String, String> workingMap = workingMapRef.get();
    //copy map content
    Map<String, String> newState = new HashMap<>(workingMap); //you can make it concurrent

    newState.put("b", "b1");
    newState.put("c", "c2");
    newState.put("d", "d1");

    return workingMapRef.compareAndSet(workingMap, newState);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest, least fuss method is to switch the map instead of replacing map contents. Whether using `volatile` or  `AtomicReference` (I don't see why you'd need `AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater` particularly), shouldn't make too much of a difference.

This makes sure that your map is always in proper state, and allows you to provide snapshots too. It doesn't protect you from other concurrency issues though, so if something like lost updates are a problem you'll need further code (although `AtomicReference` would give you `CAS` methods for handling those).

The question is actually rather simple if you only consider the complete atomic replacement of the map. It would be informative to know what other operations affect the map and how. I'd also like to hear why `ConcurrentSkipListMap` was chosen over `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: believe or not, we have such a case where we can't really do anything about the function chaining.. (long story), but the short version is that `map.computeIfAbsent("a", x -> {
            return map.computeIfAbsent("a", y -> 1);
        });` for `CHM` will fail, but it will not for the other

Comment: @Eugene I see. Sounds interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Extend a map implementation of your choice and add a synchronized method:

```
class MyReplaceMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> //or whatever
{
    public synchronized void replaceKeys(final Map<K, V> newMap)
    {
        //.. do some stuff
    }
}
```

Of course, you could always make `state` non-final volatile and re-assign it ([assignment is atomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756536/what-operations-in-java-are-considered-atomic))

```
private volatile Map<String, String> state = new HashMap<>();

//...

final Map<String, String> newState = new HashMap<>();
newState.put("b", "b1");
newState.put("c", "c2");
newState.put("d", "d1");
state = newState;
```

Comment: I *think* the OP wants to block reads, until the entire map has been updated, so if there is an update process, block reads, until updates happened, but this is just a guess

Answer (score 0):

Since the map is quite small, it's probably enough to just use `synchronized` in all places you access it.

```
private void atomicallyUpdateState(final Map<String, String> newState) {
    synchronized(state) {
        state.clear();
        state.putAll(newState);
    }
}
```

but don't forget any, like all occurances of things like

```
String myStatevalue = state.get("myValue");
```

need to become

```
String myStatevalue;
synchronized (state) {
    myStatevalue = state.get("myValue");
}
```

otherwise the read and update are not synchronized and cause a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

As client code maintains a reference to the bean not the map, replacing the value (i.e. the whole map) would seem to be the simplest solution.

Unless there's any significant performance concerns (although using locking is likely to perform worse and less predictably unless the map is huge) I'd try that before anything requiring more advanced knowledge.

It's how a functional programmer would do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ReadWriteLock` can help to automically replace all values in a Map.

```
private static final ReadWriteLock LOCK = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

private void atomicallyUpdateState(final Map<String, String> newState) {
    LOCK.writeLock().lock();
    try {
        state.clear();
        state.putAll(newState);
    } finally {
        LOCK.writeLock().unlock();
    }
}
```