# Use data generated in one thread in another thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Good morning, I'm having problems in my code I have a thread that generates a number according to the buttons are pressed and in another thread I would like to retrieve this value and send it by a method but I can't recover this value it is always reset to zero can I share this value between threads

First thread Generate data Values:

```
Thread coletaDados = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

                try {
                    while (true) {

                        dados = avancaEE + sobe + desce + avancaED + recuaED + recuaEE;

                     //   Log.i("Thread Dados", "Valor dos Dados" + dados);
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    }
                }catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
            }
        });

        coletaDados.start();


public class ThreadEnvio extends Thread {

byte[] EnvioManual = new byte[10];
ChecksumSend checksumSend = new ChecksumSend();
private  int Dados;
SerialPortManager spManager;
InseticidaManualFragment inseticidaManualFragment = new InseticidaManualFragment();
```

Second Thread use data value:

```
public ThreadEnvio()
{
//    this.Dados = dados;
    spManager = SerialPortManager.getInstances();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {

            Dados = inseticidaManualFragment.dados;
            //Dados = inseticidaManualFragment.dados;

            Log.d("Pressed", "dados" + Dados);

            EnvioManual[0] = (0x04);
            EnvioManual[1] = (0x10);
            EnvioManual[2] = (0x00);
            EnvioManual[3] = (0x00);
            EnvioManual[4] = (byte) 0xff;
            EnvioManual[5] = (0x00);
            EnvioManual[6] = (0x02);
            EnvioManual[7] = (byte) (Dados >> 8);
            EnvioManual[8] = (byte) (Dados & 0xff);
            EnvioManual[9] = checksumSend.Calculachecksum(EnvioManual);

            send(EnvioManual);

         //   Log.d("Saida", "Enviando" + toHexString(EnvioManual));
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }

    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}

public void send (byte[] x ){
    spManager.send(SerialPortManager.ttyS0,true,":" + toHexString(x) + "\r\n");
}
public static String toHexString(byte[] bytes){
    char[] hexArray = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length*2];
    int v;
    for(int j=0;j<bytes.length;j++){
        v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j*2] = hexArray[v/16];
        hexChars[j*2 + 1] = hexArray[v%16];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}
```

}

Comment: Could you edit the question to add the code where you define all these variabes: `dados = avancaEE + sobe + desce + avancaED + recuaED + recuaEE`?

Comment: see my answer to similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63271851/java-thread-and-static-variable/63271961#63271961

Answer (score 0):

The best way which I think to share data across threads using a shared object where one thread will set the value and others will retrieve.

By this, you can have synchronization over the shared object to avoid classical reader writer problem.