# why the read operation in java is atomic?

Tags: java

```
public class Hello {
static volatile int a;
public static void main(String[] args) {

    a=200;
    a=100;
    a=a+1;

}}
```

the byte code are below

```
0 sipush 200
3 putstatic #2 <jvm_test/Hello.a>
6 bipush 100
8 putstatic #2 <jvm_test/Hello.a>
11 getstatic #2 <jvm_test/Hello.a>
14 iconst_1
15 iadd
16 putstatic #2 <jvm_test/Hello.a>
19 return
```

the a=200 composed by
sipush 200 and putstatic #2
instead of one operation.
so, why we say this is atomic

Comment: What comes in between the sipush and putstatic operands?

Comment: I don't understand why you say "read operation" when you appear to be talking about the part corresponding to "a = 200". Surely that is writing?

Answer (score 4):

`sipush` pushes the number 200 to the stack, and `putstatic` assigns the value on top of the stack to the class's static field.

The reason these two bytecode instructions can be viewed together as atomic is because "the stack" is the current thread's stack; other threads have their own stacks, so they can't interfere with what's on the stack in *this* thread in between those two instructions.

If the temporary storage space for the number 200 was some shared memory that was writable by other threads, then it would indeed not be thread-safe.

Comment: +1. Somewhat related - as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4756578/6577998) also notes, atomicity does not imply visibility. Maybe that is another point of confusion for OP.