# Java multi-threaded program using join() gives wrong results in calculating sum of adjacent numbers

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-threads, java-memory-model

I wrote this simple multi-threaded program to add numbers from 1 to 100,000. When I ran this, I got different values as the end result ( values less than expected 5000050000 ). When I executed the program only using one thread, it gave correct result. Program also works for smaller values such as 100. What did possibly go wrong ? Thanks in advance.

```
class Calculation {

  private long total=0;
  public void calcSum(long start, long end) {
      long i = start;
      for( ;i<=end; i++) {
          total += i;
      }
  }
  public long getTotal() {
     return total;
  }
}

class CalculatorThread extends Thread{
   private long start;
   private long end;
   private Calculation calc;
   public CalculatorThread(long start, long end, Calculation calc) {
       this.start = start;
       this.end = end;
       this.calc = calc;
   }
   @Override
   public void run() {
       calc.calcSum(start, end);
   }
}

public class ParallelTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

      int start = 1;
      int end = 100000;

      Calculation calc = new Calculation();
      CalculatorThread ct1 = new CalculatorThread(start, end/2 , calc);
      CalculatorThread ct2 = new CalculatorThread( (end/2) + 1, end, calc);

      ct1.start();
      ct2.start();

      ct1.join();
      ct2.join();

      System.out.println(calc.getTotal());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unsynchronized access to shared mutable state usually doesn't go well.

In your `Calculation calc`, there is a mutable variable `long total`. When you start the threads:

```
  CalculatorThread ct1 = new CalculatorThread(start, end/2 , calc);
  CalculatorThread ct2 = new CalculatorThread( (end/2) + 1, end, calc);
```

you share the mutable state of `calc` between those two threads. There is no synchronization whatsoever inside `calc`, so the threads will only trash each other's memory in random time intervals.

Here is a working version:

```
class ParallelSum {
  public static long calcSum(long start, long end) {
      long total = 0;
      for(long i = start; i < end; i++) {
          total += i;
      }
      return total;
  }

  public static class CalculatorThread extends Thread {
     private long result = 0;
     private long start;
     private long end;
     public CalculatorThread(long start, long end) {
         this.start = start;
         this.end = end;
     }
     @Override
     public void run() {
         result = calcSum(start, end);
     }
     public long getResult() {
         return result;
     }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    int start = 1;
    int end = 100000;
    int endExcl = end + 1;

    CalculatorThread ct1 = new CalculatorThread(start, endExcl/2);
    CalculatorThread ct2 = new CalculatorThread(endExcl / 2, endExcl);

    ct1.start();
    ct2.start();

    ct1.join();
    ct2.join();

    System.out.println(ct1.getResult() + ct2.getResult());
  }
}
```

Outputs:

```
5000050000
```

Additional note: always use `[inclusive, exclusive)` indexing of ranges. This decreases the chance for off-by-one errors dramatically. Also, I've replaced the `Calculation` class by a method: nothing can go wrong with local variables, inside a method, and the less mutable state there is, the better.

Answer (score 3):

The class `Calculation` is not thread safe, and you are using the same instance on two threads. So each thread is replacing the value set by the other.

A simple solution will be to create two `Calculation` instances, one for every `CalculatorThread`.

```
Calculation calc1 = new Calculation();
Calculation calc2 = new Calculation();
CalculatorThread ct1 = new CalculatorThread(start, end/2 , calc1);
CalculatorThread ct2 = new CalculatorThread( (end/2) + 1, end, calc2);
```

This is a classic calculation that can be broken down to independent parts (that can execute concurrently) and reduced to a single result at the end.

Answer (score 0):

`total += i` is not atomic (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32676836/9589593)). You have two threads modifying the same value `total` at the same time, and the two threads are interfering with each other.

Take a look at `AtomicLong` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html)), which has a method `addAndGet` that atomically adds some number:

```
class Calculation {
    private AtomicLong total = new AtomicLong();
    public void calcSum(long start, long end) {
        long i = start;
        for( ;i<=end; i++) {
            total.addAndGet(i);
        }
    }
    public long getTotal() {
       return total.get();
    }
}
```

With this approach, both threads can add to `total` atomically, so they won't interfere anymore.

Comment: Those two calculations can be performed completely independently, one single `+` is required in the very end. No reason to share any state at all between threads here.

Comment: Indeed. But that's only because the OP is learning/practicing with a toy problem. Using atomic operations is a more general solution, so I think my answer is more educational. (What if there was a third thread that needed to periodically print out the "current total"?)

Comment: Fair enough, one should know about all possible options and techniques. Showing how it works with atomics certainly has educational value. :]

Answer (score 0):

this is not the easiest way to achieve your result. If you want to calculate the sum of numbers from 1 to N you should use this formula:
sum from 1 to N = N(N+1)/2. You are facing with what is called inconsistent reading. Your two threads are sharing the same field "calc" and expecially the long field total of Calculation class. 
With your solution this can happens:

trhead1 reads a total equals to 0,
thread1 increment the value of total to 1,
thread2 reads a total equals to 0,
thread2 increment the value of total to 1.

Other scenarios are possible with your solution, the fact is that in this way the value of total is not predictible.So use the provided formula or a simple for, don't use async solution for a sync problem.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem with your code is that the `Calculation` is effectively a wrapper for a shared variable (the `count` field) which is being updated without any synchronization.

There are three ways to solve this:

- synchronize the variable; e.g. by using `synchronized` at the appropriate points
- use an atomic type for the variable
- don't use a shared variable.

The third option is better from a performance perspective, and the implementation is straight-forward; see @JenniferP's answer.

Note that no extra synchronization is required if you give each thread its own `Calculation` object.  The *happens before* relations that are associated with the `Thread::start()` and `Thread::join()` calls ensure that the main thread sees the correct results from the child threads when it reads them after the join.

---

For what it is worth, a thread-safe implementation of `Calculation` that will work when the instance is shared would look like this:

```
  class Calculation {

      private long total = 0;

      public void calcSum(long start, long end) {        
          for (long i = start; i <= end; i++) {
              increment(i);
          }
      }

      public synchronized long getTotal() {
         return total;
      }

      private synchronized void increment(long by) {
         total += by;
      }
  }
```

Note that you need to synchronize both on the getter and the increment method.  An alternative is to use an `AtomicLong` to represent the total.  But in both cases there will be a significant amount of overhead due to the use of the shared variable.  (In the version with `synchronized`, the overhead could be extreme due to lock contention.  I would be surprised if there was any speedup at all compared with the single-threaded version.   Even if you could eliminate the thread creation overheads.)