# Micrometer/Prometheus: How to measure processing duration?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I want to measure how long it takes to process some data: My application reads that data from a given source at a fixed rate. Before each circle I store `Instant.now()`. I read the data, adding that single timestamp to each entry. The data gets stored, converted, and just before I send it out via WebSockets, I want to measure the duration between `now()` and that initial timestamp.

I tried

```
long millis = Duration.between(dataEntry.getReceivedTimestamp(), Instant.now()).toMillis();
LOG.info(millis + "ms");
registry.timer("processingDuration").record(millis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

but visualizing this allows me to use only `processingDuration_seconds_count`, `_max` and `_sum`. `count` and `sum` increase over time (of course), `max` is constant most of the time. So how do I see higher and lower plateaus of load? I tried `irate(processingDuration_seconds_sum[10m])` to see jumps at least, but as `irate()` uses two datapoints only, I still cannot identify longer periods of high load easily. Plus: The value is around 0.6 in the graph, while the logged ms are around 5-10, so I'm losing the actual value here.

So I tried to use a `Gauge` instead – which is supposed to allow both increasing and decreasing values:

```
registry.gauge("processingDurationGauge", millis);
```

I'd thought this would go up and down within the range of the logged ms, but it's constantly 92.

How do I measure throughout time of data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a timer and `record` is the correct solution.

```
long millis = Duration.between(dataEntry.getReceivedTimestamp(), Instant.now()).toMillis();
LOG.info(millis + "ms");
registry.timer("processingDuration").record(millis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Assuming you are scraping every 30 seconds you can us the `_sum` and `_count` to get the average recorded duration:

```
increase(processingDuration_seconds_sum[1m])/increase(processingDuration_seconds_count[1m])
```

And if you wanted to compare how the current duration is behaving compared to the average over the last day:

```
((increase(processingDuration_seconds_sum[1m])/
increase(processingDuration_seconds_count[1m]))*1.50) >
increase(processingDuration_seconds_sum[24h])/
increase(processingDuration_seconds_count[24h])
```

That would only return values where the 1m average is more that 1.5x the daily average. (I haven't tested that query, but it should get the idea).

Comment: What's the advantage of this compared to the Gauge? I see a disadvantage: The resulting graph never matches to logged milliseconds

Comment: Just saw [this documentation](https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/prometheus#_timers) which looks similar (they use `rate()`). Anyways: As this pointed me in the right direction I'll accept it in a minute. Thanks again

Comment: I'm very confused - prometheus exports this as seconds even though I add to the timer milliseconds. So does prometheus convert it to seconds? Or does it dispaly the actual recorded milliseconds but it labels it seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was, `long` isn't thread safe, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9278798/3890673). Doing it [as documented](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_manually_incrementingdecrementing_a_gauge) works as expected:

```
private final AtomicLong processingDuration;

// ...

// in constructor:
processingDuration = meterRegistry.gauge("processingDuration", new AtomicLong(0L));

// ...

// before finishing the data entries' handling:
long millis = Duration.between(dataEntry.getReceivedTimestamp(), Instant.now()).toMillis();
LOG.info(millis + "ms");
processingDuration.set(millis);
```