# Does atomic variables guarantee memory visibility?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, atomic, memory-visibility

Small question about memory visibility.

**CodeSample1:**

```
class CustomLock {

    private boolean locked = false;

    public boolean lock() {
        if(!locked) {
            locked = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This code is prone to bugs in a multi-threaded environment, first because of the "if-then-act" which is not atomic, and second because of potential memory visibility issues where for example threadA sets the field to true, but threadB that later wishes to read the field's value might not see that, and still see the value false.

The simplest solution is to use the synchronized keyword, as in CodeSample2.

**CodeSample2:**

```
class CustomLock {

    private boolean locked = false;

    public synchronized boolean lock() {
        if(!locked) {
            locked = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now what if I wish to use an atomic variable, and for the example, an AtomicBoolean (question applies to all atomic variables),

**CodeSample3:**

```
   public static class CustomLock {
    private AtomicBoolean locked = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public boolean lock() {
        return locked.compareAndSet(false, true);
    }
}
```

Better performance considerations aside, we can see that now we've implemented similar logic to the "if-then-act" from **CodeSample1**, using AtomicBoolean.
It doesn't really matter what the code does logically, ***the question I have is*** what if 2 threads invoke the lock() method in **CodeSample3** right about the same time, while it's clear that any write operation to the field will now be done atomically, does the use of AtomicBoolean also guarantees memory visibility?

Sorry for the long story, just wanted to make sure I'm coming across as clear as possible, Thanks guys...

Answer (score 13):

Yes, according to the [javadocs it guarantees](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html#package_description):

> compareAndSet and all other read-and-update operations such as getAndIncrement have the memory effects of both reading and writing volatile variables.

Comment: @JamesJenkins it's usually, darned near always actually, useful to read the documentation when you have a question.

Answer (score 3):

> the question I have is what if 2 threads invoke the lock() method in CodeSample3 right about the same time, while it's clear that any write operation to the field will now be done atomically, does the use of AtomicBoolean also guarantees memory visibility?

For `AtomicBoolean` to handle multiple operations from different threads at the same time it *has* to guarantee memory visibility.  It can make the guarantee because it wraps a `volatile` field.  It is the language semantics of the `volatile` which ensures that memory barriers are crossed so that multiple threads see the most up to date value and that any updates will be published to main memory.

Btw, your `lock(...)` method should ready be `tryLock(...)` because it might not get the lock.

Comment: whatever it wraps or not are implementation details, the documentation is the place to look at. you can have a `synchronized` method that *is* atomic, but if the shared data that is updated inside it is exposed without synchronizing on the same lock, there is no visibility guarantee

Comment: I think I've commented on the wrong answer :| sorry