# Volatile keyword not able to use properly

Tags: java, volatile, java-threads

I get the same output with and without the `volatile` keyword.

Have I made a mistake in the code?

```java
public class MutliThreadExample extends Thread{

    volatile int value;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        MutliThreadExample thread1 = new MutliThreadExample();
        MutliThreadExample thread2 = new MutliThreadExample();
        thread1.start();
        thread1.join();
        thread2.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            value = value + 1;
            System.out.println(value + "-" + Thread.currentThread());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I am not able to use `volatile` keyword properly in Java.

Comment: `value = value + 1` requires an `AtomicInteger`, not just a volatile.

Comment: Hi & welcome! :) ..maybe...but: `thread1.start();thread1.join();thread2.start();` *is sequential* (i.e. *not parallel*)

Comment: `volatile` makes reads and writes atomic, but not their combination.  See, for example, https://www.scaler.com/topics/volatile-keyword-in-java/.  Incrementing a volatile variable is _not_ safe and needs a full `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman `volatile` is not about atomicity, do not please confuse others: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744508/volatile-vs-atomic#:~:text=Volatile%20and%20Atomic%20are%20two,on%20variables%20are%20performed%20atomically.

Comment: Each instance of `MutliThreadExample` has its own `value`, so there is only one thread accessing it anyway; volatile isn't really necessary for your code.

Comment: @Mikhail2048 - Actually, atomicity *can* come into it.  JLS 17.7 says: *"For the purposes of the Java programming language memory model, a single write to a **non-volatile** long or double value is treated as two separate writes: one to each 32-bit half. This can result in a situation where a thread sees the first 32 bits of a 64-bit value from one write, and the second 32 bits from another write."*.

Comment: Note that it is implementation specific whether a JVM is actually subject to "word tearing" issues with non-volatile `long` and `double` shared variables.

Comment: @StephenC - yes, if we are talking about the atomicity of double and long writes that's ok. But this atomicity is achieved on the CPU level on 64-bit machines, and almost all of the machines today are 64-bit, including mobile devices. I am not saying you are wrong, I am saying that the author is using a ridiculous example which is not relevant at all - he uses an integer.

Comment: That's not what your comment **says**.  You respond to a *general* comment about what volatile with an (incorrect) general denial.

Answer (score 7):

> Am I doing anything wrong in this ?

Yes.  Multiple things.

Firstly, your application is effectively single-threaded (NOT multi-threaded) because of this:

```
    thread1.start();
    thread1.join();
    thread2.start();
```

What that says is

1. Start thread1
2. Wait for thread1 to finish
3. Start thread2.

So thread1 and thread2 will not be running at the same time.

Secondly, the threads do this:

```
    Thread.sleep(1000);
```

When you call `sleep`, variable values that are cached in registers, etcetera are liable to be written to main memory.  That is liable to make this code behave differently, and interfere with any observations you are attempting to make.

Thirdly, they do this:

```
    System.out.println(value + "-" + Thread.currentThread());
```

In the `println` call, the I/O stack typically does some synchronization under the hood, and *that* will also interfere with the observation of `value`.  Furthermore `value` may have changed since you incremented it.

Fourthly, you increment the variable like this:

```
    value = value + 1;
```

That is not an atomic operation, even when `value` is declared as `volatile`.  It is in fact a read operation followed by an addition followed by a write operation.  The same would be true if you wrote

```
    value++;  // or ++value;
```

If two threads *actually* execute these statement simultaneously, they are liable to *occasionally* lose an increment due to the interleaving of the read, add, and write operations on the shared variable from different threads.

(Declaring a variable as `volatile` gives a *happens before* relationship between a write of the variable by one thread a subsequent reads of the same variable by other threads.  But that is not sufficient to implement a counter that can be updated by two or more threads in a thread-safe fashion.   To do that you need to use `synchronized`, an `AtomicInteger` or equivalent.)

Finally, you have declared `value` as an instance variable of `MutliThreadExample`, and `thread1` and `thread2` are different instances of that class.  That means that `thread1` and `thread2` are updating *different* `value` variables.  There is no shared variable, so the whole example is moot!

---

In summary your code produces the same output in both versions because it is not multi-threaded.  The `sleep` and `println` calls are also liable to interfere with the "observations".  And the threads are updating *different* `value` variables anyway.

If you fixed all of those problems, your code is *not thread-safe*, either with the `volatile` or without it.  Neither version would be guaranteed produce either correct or incorrect answers.  They would both have non-deterministic behavior.

Reliably demonstrating the effects of `volatile` is difficult.  And making basic programming mistakes doesn't help.