# Is there a name for the algorithm used by HotSpot for class herarchy analysis?

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, jit, jvm-hotspot

I see that some optimizations used by Hotspot have names, e.g. [chaitin](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/openjdk/jdk8/hotspot/src/share/vm/opto/chaitin.hpp) for graph coloring. What is the name of the algorithm used by Hotspot for class hierarchy analysis?

Comment: 'Chaitin' is really a version of the Briggs-Chaitin register colouring algorithm. As Java class hierarchies are linear I don't know why its 'class hierarchy analysis' would be of any special complexity or interest.

Comment: @EJP, you mean to say most probably it wouldn't have a name because class hierarchy analysis is very easy to implement? I'm looking for the code too, so I think if the people of HotSpot named the source file differently, I would find it easier.

Comment: @EJP, I also have a question on Strings that could involve the "special task" accomplished by class hierarchy analysis. Hope you could help. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25442323/thread-safety-of-the-plus-operator-for-strings-optimizations-included